# Open an excel file and write values to

Tags: vba

I want to open an excel sheet and write values to it.

Therefore I wrote this

```
Private Sub Test()

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkBook As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Marc\Dropbox\PROJECTEN\Lopend\office_VA\macroStore.xlsx", True, False)
xlWorkBook.sheets(1).Range("A2").Select

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWorkBook = Nothing


End Sub
```

This all works. But the thing is that now everytime a new excel file is opened. And I just would like to open an existing one. Any thoughts on how to change this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkBook As Object
Dim path As String
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True

path = "C:\Users\Marc\Dropbox\PROJECTEN\Lopend\office_VA\macroStore.xlsx"
If IsFileOpen(path) Then
    Set xlWorkBook = GetObject(path)
Else
    Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path)
End If

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWorkBook = Nothing

End Sub

Function IsFileOpen(filename As String)
    Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer

    On Error Resume Next   ' Turn error checking off.
    filenum = FreeFile()   ' Get a free file number.
    ' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
    Open filename For Input Lock Read As #filenum
    Close filenum          ' Close the file.
    errnum = Err           ' Save the error number that occurred.
    On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.

    ' Check to see which error occurred.
    Select Case errnum

        ' No error occurred.
        ' File is NOT already open by another user.
        Case 0
         IsFileOpen = False

        ' Error number for "Permission Denied."
        ' File is already opened by another user.
        Case 70
            IsFileOpen = True

        ' Another error occurred.
        Case Else
            Error errnum
    End Select

End Function
```

Note: Function is taken from [Microsoft site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291295/macro-code-to-check-whether-a-file-is-already-open)

Comment: @Henk Straten I edited my answer since you do not work with Excel VBA